# Double curly braces in perl

Tags: perl, curly-braces

I was looking at perl code online and came across something I hadn't seen before and can't find out what it's doing (if anything).

```
if($var) {{
   ...
}}
```

Does anyone know what the double curly braces mean?

Comment: I don't think they do anything. I think they are equivalent to adding another block of code in the if block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a trick usually employed with `do`, see [chapter *Statement Modifiers* in `perlsyn`](http://p3rl.org/syn#Statement-Modifiers).

Probably the author wanted to jump out of the block with `next` or the like.

Comment: This appears to be what the code is doing. The last keyword is used in the code in the if block.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

There are two statements there. An "if" statement and a [bare block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Basic-BLOCKs). Bare blocks are loops that are executed exactly once.

```
say "a";
{
   say "b";
}
say "c";

# Outputs a b c
```

But being loops, they do influence `next`, `last` and `redo`.

```
my $i = 0;
say "a";
LOOP: {  # Purely descriptive (and thus optional) label.
   ++$i;
   say "b";
   redo if $i == 1;
   say "c";
   last if $i == 2;
   say "d";
}
say "e";

# Outputs a b b c e
```

(`next` does the same as `last` since there is no next element.)

They are usually used to create a lexical scope.

```
my $file;
{
   local $/;
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die;
   $file = <$fh>;
}
# At this point,
# - $fh is cleared,
# - $fh is no longer visible,
# - the file handle is closed, and
# - $/ is restored.
```

It's unclear why one was used here.

---

Alternatively, it could also be a hash constructor.

```
sub f {
   ...
   if (@errors) {
      { status => 'error', errors => \@errors }
   } else {
      { status => 'ok' }
   }
}
```

is short for

```
sub f {
   ...
   if (@errors) {
      return { status => 'error', errors => \@errors };
   } else {
      return { status => 'ok' };
   }
}
```

Perl peeks into the braces to guess if it's a bare loop or a hash constructor. Since you didn't provide the contents of the braces, we can't tell.

Answer (score 4):

In case of `if`, they are probably equivalent to single braces (but it depends on what's inside the block and outside the `if`, cf.

```
perl -E ' say for map { if (1) {{ 1,2,3,4 }} } 1 .. 2'
```

). There are reasons to use double braces, though, with `next` or `do`, see [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers). For example, try running this several times:

```
perl -E 'if (1) {{ say $c++; redo if int rand 2 }}'
```

And try to replace double braces with single ones.

Answer (score 0):

Without much more code, it's hard to say what they're being used for. It could be a typo, or it could be a naked block, see [chapter 10.4 *The Naked Block Control Structure* in **Learning Perl**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452).

A naked block adds lexical scoping to variables within the block.

Comment: Doesn't the first set of braces after the `if` already provide that scoping? Why nest? I'm largely ignorant of perl, so maybe it's obvious to people, but not to me!

Comment: @ChrisFarmer: because `if (1) {{ my $x = 1; } { my $x = 2; }}`

Comment: By adding the second scope, you could reassign `$var` and use it in the naked block in a way that is not visible outside of the if block.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, daxim. I thought I had linked to an article on O'Reilly because that site looked so much like the [O'Reilly equivalent](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lperl3/chapter/ch04.html)

Answer (score 0):

The {{ can be used to break out of an "if block". I have some code that contains:

```
if ($entry =~ m{\nuid: ([^\s]+)}) {{ # double brace so "last" will break out of "if"
    my $uid = $1;
    last if exists $special_case{$uid};
    # ....

}}
# last breaks to here
```